# Creating NDVI and Cloud Chart in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, ndvi, sentinel-2, time-series, geemap

I am trying to calculate NDVI and cloud pixel percentage. I have successfully done this but I am facing a problem in creating a chart of it in Jupyter Notebook, as I am new to Python so I tried various methods but no one worked.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import ee
import geemap
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Initialize Earth Engine
ee.Initialize()

# Load the shapefile using GeoPandas
nReserve = gpd.read_file('D:/test/Chichawatni.shp')

# Create a GeoJSON representation from the GeoPandas dataframe
nReserve_geojson = geemap.gdf_to_ee(nReserve)

# Create a map for displaying the results
Map = geemap.Map()

# Calculate NDVI
def calculate_ndvi(image):
    # Get the 'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE' property of the image
    cloudPercentage = ee.Number(image.get('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE'))

    # Calculate NDVI
    ndviImage = image.expression(
        '(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)',
        {
            'NIR': image.select('B8'),
            'RED': image.select('B4'),
        }
    ).float().rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])

    # Add the 'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE' property as an image property
    return ndviImage.set('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloudPercentage) 
    
start_date = '2023-10-20'
end_date = '2023-10-27'

# Define the Sentinel-2 collection
sentinel2_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED').filterDate(start_date, end_date)

# Filter the collection by date and AOI
filtered_collection = sentinel2_collection.filterBounds(nReserve_geojson).filterDate(start_date, end_date)

# Calculate NDVI for the filtered collection
ndvi_collection = filtered_collection.map(calculate_ndvi)

# Clip the NDVI to the shapefile
ndvi_clip = ndvi_collection.mean().clip(nReserve_geojson)

Map.centerObject(nReserve_geojson, 10)  # Center the map on the shapefile

# Add the shapefile as an image layer
nReserve_image = ee.Image().paint(nReserve_geojson, 0, 2)
Map.addLayer(nReserve_image, {'palette': 'red'}, 'Shapefile')

# Add the NDVI layer on top
ndvi_viz_params = {
    'min': -1,
    'max': 1,
    'palette': ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301']
}
Map.addLayer(ndvi_clip, ndvi_viz_params, 'NDVI')


# Create a list of dates and 'CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE' values for the chart
def createChartData(image):
    date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'))
    ndviValue = image.reduceRegion(
        reducer = ee.Reducer.mean(), 
        geometry = nReserve_geojson, 
        scale = 10,
    maxPixels= 1e13).get('NDVI')
    cloudPercentage = image.get('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
    return ee.Feature(None, {
        'date': date,
        'NDVI': ndviValue,
        'Cloudy Percentage': cloudPercentage
    })
chartData = ndvi_collection.map(createChartData)

# Display the map with shapefile and NDVI layer
Map
```

Answer (score 0):

You've only created a GEE feature collection object `chartData`.

To display the data as a chart, you'll first need to download the feature collection object's data locally with `chartData_local = chartData.getInfo()`.

Then convert that to a geopandas dataframe for simple, more organised access, with `chartData_organised_local = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(chartData_local)`.

Finally, plot the geopandas frames using for example matplotlib. This is done by simply doing:

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(chartData_organised_local['date'],chartData_organised_local['NDVI'])
plt.ylabel('NDVI')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(chartData_organised_local['date'],chartData_organised_local['Cloudy Percentage'])
plt.ylabel('Cloud Coverage')
```

Complete code you'll need to add at the end of yours:

```
chartData_local = chartData.getInfo()
chartData_organised_local = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(chartData_local)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(chartData_organised_local['date'],chartData_organised_local['NDVI'])
plt.ylabel('NDVI')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(chartData_organised_local['date'],chartData_organised_local['Cloudy Percentage'])
plt.ylabel('Cloud Coverage')
```